# TYPO3 - how to call action from controller in scheduler task

Tags: typo3, task, scheduler

I have extension with some actions in my controller. How can I call one of these action in my scheduler task?

In file mwextension/Classes/Task/Task.php I want to call in "public function execute()" the "public function datenimportAction()" which is located "mwextension/Classes/Controller/MyController.php"

Thanks for help!
Martin

Comment: I found some solution - but this does not inject repository: $objectManager = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Object\\ObjectManager');
     $datenimport = GeneralUtility::makeInstance('xxx\\ddd\\Controller\\xxxController');
     $datenimport->datenimportAction($settingsForAction);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are nearly there. Just instantiate all the extbasey stuff with `ObjectManager->get`.

```
$objectManager = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(
  \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManager::class
); 
$controller = $objectManager->get(
  \xxx\ddd\Controller\xxxController::class
); 
$controller->datenimportAction($settingsForAction);
```